# Dynamic include statement with conditional statements EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

i have something like this to bring a entity with related info:

```
var includes = new string[]{"Relation1","Relation2"}; //Relation2 has many records

IQueryable<TEntity> IQuery = _dbContext.Set<TEntity>();

foreach (string toInclude in includes)
{
  IQuery = IQuery.Include(toInclude);  //Make a conditional statement here!!          
} 

return IQuery;
```

this works fine to me but "toInclude" in some cases could be a one to many relatioship, so how could I use a conditional statement, to get filtered records from (toInclude).

Comment: Unless you want to deep dive in to Expression Trees, I highly recommend a library like [Dynamic LINQ](https://dynamic-linq.net/).

Comment: Hi  Bradley Uffner, i've tried with dynamic, but i'cant get the inner data... the filter only affects the parent.
IQuery.Include(toInclude).Where("Entity.DeletedDate == null");